# Crear directorios y ficheros en cualquier parte de sistema

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy intentando crear un directorio con un CLI que estoy haciendo en node y solo puedo crear ficheros y directorios en la carpeta del proyecto, no pudiendo dar cualquier ruta del sistema y crear directorios allá dónde el usuario quiera. Os dejo el planteamiento que estoy realizando:

```
    return inquirer.prompt(question).then(function (answers) {
        dir = answers.dir;
        newdir = answers.newdir;

        if (dir !== '' && newdir !== '') {
            if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
                if (!fs.existsSync(newdir)) {
                    fs.mkdirSync(newdir, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('An error occurred: ' + err);
                            return process.exit(1);
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('Directory created successfully.');
                }
            }
        }

        return process.exit(1);
    })
```

dir es la ruta donde quiere crear el usuario el nuevo directorio (nueva carpeta) y newdir el nombre de la misma.

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Para crear carpetas o archivos en "cualquier parte de sistema", el usuario del sistema operativo que ejecuta nodejs tiene que tener permiso para hacerlo, supongamos un usuario root. Dar un usuario root/admin a nodejs y por consiguiente a los ususrios de este, es algo que no es recomendable en absoluto.

Comment: Otra opción es ejecutar bash, pero es aún peor, ya que expondrías las credenciales root/admin.

Comment: @Emeeus gracias por la respuesta. Es un mini proyecto para uso propio, y en caso de querer compartirlo con un amigo, no habría inconveniente en que cada uno de nosotros pueda tener todos los permisos para crear directorios y ficheros en nuestro propio PC verdad? En todo caso, cómo se haría en node? Muchas gracias